# ARM Templates: conditionally add to array

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

For my Azure ARM templates, I want to conditionally add an extra NSG rule. If parameter is true, append extra rule to the "securityRules" array.  How do I efficiently go about this?  I can't use the "condition" properties for nested objects. Creating two resources seems clunky.

Answer (score 8):

Depending on a condition, you would like to add an additional (string) value to an existing json array. This can be done via the concat function. In order to concat an array and a string value, the string value will need to be transformed into an array too. When the condition is true, the two arrays can be concatenated. When the condition is false, you can concatenate the existing string with an empty array.

```
"[concat( parameters('existingArray'), if( parameters('condition'), array('Cc'), variables('emptyArray')) )]"
```

Assuming the orriginal array is: ["Aa", "Bb"]

- When the condition is true, this will result in: ["Aa", "Bb", "Cc"]
- When the condition is false, this will result in: ["Aa", "Bb"]

Answer (score 1):

Some of the existing answers have similar info, but not explicit enough. So here's a detailed answer.

So let's say you have two sets of NSG rule variables `defaultNSGRules` and `additionalNSGRules` and they both are array of rules.

To be able to add the additional rules, you can check for a condition, and if  met, concatenate the additional rules, otherwise, an empty array. To do this you need 2 things:

1. A condition. This can be a variable or parameter where you check for a specific value. For simplicity, let's say it'a `bool` with name of `shuoldUseAdditionalNSGRules`. But you can check a string value, etc.
2. An empty array variable defined like this: `"emptyArray": []`. This is necessary as the ARM template doesn't like using `[]` in the if statement of the concat call

then you can use this to append the additional rules when the bool is set to true:

```json
"securityRules": "[concat(variables('defaultNSGRules'), if (parameters('shuoldUseAdditionalNSGRules'), variables('additionalNSGRules'), variables('emptyArray')))]"
```

Answer (score 0):

Overthought it.  Variables are allowed to be defined as arrays. Define two variables, each with the different set of rules. Apply "if" function to securityRules base on parameter "allowInternetAccess".

Comment: seems like a lot of duplication

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

In my parameter file (JSON) operations are defined as follows (this is not the complete parameter file)

```
"Operation1": {
    "name": "operation-1",
    ...
},
"Operation2": {}
```

Bicep handling for operations:

```
var allOperations = [
    apiManagement.api.operations.Operation1
    apiManagement.api.operations.Operation2
]

var usedOperations = [
    apiManagement.api.operations.Operation1
    empty(apiManagement.api.operations.Operation2) ? null : apiManagement.api.operations.Operation2
]

var operations = intersection(allOperations, usedOperations)

module api_operation './shared/api-operation.bicep' = [for operation in operations: {
  name: '${apiManagement.api.name}-${operation.name}'
  params: {
    apiManagement: apiManagement
    operation: operation
  } 
}]
```